# Adding to an ArrayList of a class object?

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

```
public static ArrayList<Lecturer> lecturers = new ArrayList<Lecturer>();
lecturers.add(Lecturer);

public Lecturer (String name, String id, String address, String email, String office, String phone_number, String research, Module mod){
    super(name, id, address, email, office, phone_number);
    this.research = research;
    this.mod = mod;
}
```

Hi all,
I have created a class and a constructor called Lecturer which stores details about Lecturers. I have also created an ArrayList of the type Lecturer which stores objects of lecturers. However, when I try to add to the list I keep getting the error " expected". I know there is something wrong with the "add(Lecturer)" part but I can't seem to figure out what else to write instead. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why are you adding *the class*? `ArrayList<Lecturer>` contain `Lecturer` instances, not the class itself!

Comment: I do not know what else to put inside... I am a beginer.

Comment: I already told you - a `Lecturer` instance!

Comment: And at the right place in the program. Where it is now, it's invalid syntax.

Comment: like lecturers.add(new Lecturer()); i recommend using an IDE like eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding real instances  (and inside a method):

```
public void addLecturer(...) {
  // 
  lecturers.add(new Lecturer(....));
}
```

A more complete version

```
class Lecturers {

  public static ArrayList<Lecturer> lecturers = new ArrayList<Lecturer>();

  public static void addLecturer(Lecturer lecturer) {
    lecturers.add(lecturer);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lecturer one = new Lecturer(...)
    addLecturer(one);
  }
}


// you should extend a super Lecturer type
class Lecturer extends ... {

public Lecturer(String name, String id, String address, String email,   String office, String phone_number, String research, Module mod) {
    super(name, id, address, email, office, phone_number);
    this.research = research;
    this.mod = mod;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't add real instances since there is not meant to be a main class (it's a requirement set) however, the ArrayList has to be able to store the Lecturer details.

Comment: The data structure you declared will contain object instances. Please update the description if you have any specific constraints/requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
lecturers.add(new Lecturer(name, id.....etc));
```

You need to use the `new` operator when creating the object, not the Class itself!

Comment: lecturers.add(new Lecturer(name, id, address, email, office, phone_number, research, mod));

Comment: I still get an error when I use that... along with errors about missing ")" and ";" symbols.

Comment: @assasinweed2 Right now it is not 100% clear exactly where should try and put it. If you can include your `Lecturer` Class code then it would be easier for everybody to try and help you.